# laravel how to set memory limit on each job in the queue?

Tags: php, memory, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I used laravel queue job to do some time costing work. I use node to do 3d model calculating in the job. While some 3d model file is too big, it will throw this error,

> ```
> > RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> >     at /var/www/market/node/STL.js:311:83
> >     at powell_opt (/var/www/market/node/STL.js:354:38)
> >     at STL.computeFlatAngle (/var/www/market/node/STL.js:241:13)
> >     at STL.getFlatAngle (/var/www/market/node/STL.js:200:18)
> >     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/market/node/slice.js:6:24)
> >     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
> >     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
> >     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
> >     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
> >     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10) [2017-09-15 18:03:37]
> > Failed:     App\Jobs\SliceModel [2017-09-15 18:04:37]
> > Processing: App\Jobs\SliceModel
> ```

So how to set the memory limit for each queued job, I have read the Laravel Queues doc, but find nothing.

Comment: The error is coming from Node, not from Laravel queue. There is nothing you can do to Laravel to overcome that error. It seems you reached the maximum recursivity level of Node, so either increase that limit, either debug your code because it seems you have an infinite recursive loop

Comment: I think here node is a subprocess of php, laravel have limit on it's queued job, so the job will also limit the memory of its subprocess.

Comment: @JaviStolz wait for a minute, to locate the problem, I run the same node script on the console  to check it now.

Comment: @JaviStolz you're right, I just run the node script on the console, also get the same error. I run optimization to find the local minium value of the 3d model. So there need much memory cost. For small model, it's OK. So I need to find how to set the limit for node. Thank you.

Comment: `nodejs --v8-options` is `--stack_size (default size of stack region v8 is allowed to use (in kBytes))
        type: int  default: 984`
So I set it to 10M with `node --stack-size=10240 slice.js ./Jack_O_Lantern1.STL` in the php `exec()`, and it works OK. For most of the model si no more than 8M.